# How to manage the tkinter label frames geometry

Tags: python, tkinter

**NOTE: The managing works for dummy label frames, but didn't work for actual app**

I am trying to place the 4 label frames into a frame snuggly. I have tried with the dummy label frame, for the simple script it works perfectly, but for the actual application with a lot of real functions and many buttons, it did not work. I have spent hours trying to fix the problem but all went to no avail.

**Question: How to remove the gap between row0 and row1 label frames and display all four geometries snuggly?**

## MWE

```py
#=============================================================================
#==== Frame: contains labelframes
f = tk.Frame(win,height=200, width=200)

f.grid(row=2,column=3,padx=2, pady=2)
f.pack(fill="both", expand="yes")


# label frames
kw = dict(rowspan=1,columnspan=1,f=f,win=win,padx=2, pady=2)

kwp = dict(path_app=path_app,path_snippets_json=path_snippets_json)
kw_most = {**kw,**kwp}

label_frame_find_and_replace(   row=0,column=0,sticky='new', **kw)
label_frame_most_used(row=1,column=0,sticky='ns',**kw_most)

label_frame_move_from_downloads(row=0,column=1,sticky='nw', **kw)
label_frame_move_from_documents(row=0,column=2,sticky='ne', **kw)

#=============================================================================
# #==== Grid configuration
# f.rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
# f.rowconfigure(1,weight=1)

# f.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
# f.columnconfigure(1,weight=1)
# f.columnconfigure(2,weight=1)

#=============================================================================
#==== Run the app in infinite loop
win.config(menu=menubar)
win.mainloop()
```

## Image

[image]

**Question: How to remove the gap between row0 and row1 label frames and display all four geometries snuggly?**

Comment: Looking quickly: you may need to add `rowspan=2` to the grid call for the frame on the right. Noticed code mixes grid and pack...hmm, think it best to use only one geometry manager.

Comment: Will you elaborate more, i am most familiar with writing codes in python but this is my first attempt to create GUI using tkinter, so very new to tkinter.

Comment: Might elaborate more when I have time, got work meeting in two minutes...but quickly I would use grid everywhere and pack nowhere. To bridge gap problems like that use columnspan=# and rowspan=# to make one item take up more than one row or column. Some people can do it all in pack, which I don't use much.

Comment: Seems like Collaxd already did an excellent job elaborating in his answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your problem is not in the size of the frames on the left, but in the widget on the right, which occupies more size, the limitation, in this case, extending your frame is in it
[image: Gap Problem]

So for example, if you have 3 identical widgets no problem appears, they are all where they should be, that way.

```py
import tkinter

app = tkinter.Tk()
app.geometry('400x400')

for i in range(2):
    app.columnconfigure(index=i, weight=1)

size_1 = {'width': 100, 'height': 100}
# size_2 = {'width': 100, 'height': 250}

fr1 = tkinter.Frame(app, bg='red', **size_1)
fr1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='news')

fr2 = tkinter.Frame(app, bg='blue', **size_1)
fr2.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='news')

fr3 = tkinter.Frame(app, bg='green', **size_1)
fr3.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='news')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.mainloop()
```

[image: Example 1]

Now note that when component 3 'FR3' has a bigger size tall, it moves 'FR1' along with it, because it is a grid where everyone is equal
The code is the same, I just added size 2 to the 'fr3' widget

```py
fr3 = tkinter.Frame(app, bg='green', **size_2)
```

[image: Example 2]

So, in short, my solution is to use rowspan in the 'fr3' component, so it will occupy two or more lines, 'as many as necessary', and it won't disturb the left component

Final code..

```py
import tkinter

app = tkinter.Tk()
app.geometry('400x400')

for i in range(2):
    app.columnconfigure(index=i, weight=1)

size_1 = {'width': 100, 'height': 100}
size_2 = {'width': 100, 'height': 250}

fr1 = tkinter.Frame(app, bg='red', **size_1)
fr1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='news')

fr2 = tkinter.Frame(app, bg='blue', **size_1)
fr2.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='news')

fr3 = tkinter.Frame(app, bg='green', **size_2)
fr3.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='news', rowspan=2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.mainloop()
```

[image: Exempla 3]